# aws codebuild running multiple times

Tags: aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild, aws-code-deploy

I have built CI/CD pipeline using AWS code pipeline -> codeBuild -> code deploy,

Edit: added manual approval after the code pipeline seems like code build is triggering the git source

When there is any change in GitHub,

1. code pipeline(source) is triggered
2. codeBuild which in turn creates a docker image and pushes it to ECR
3. code deploy run build.sh file and create a docker container in the ec2 instance.

Everything runs fine as expected but the code-build part is looping(running again and again) which triggers code-deploy again and again.

> buildspec.yml

```
version: 0.2
phases:
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo Logging in to Amazon ECR...
      - aws ecr get-login-password --region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin $AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION.amazonaws.com
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Build started on `date`
      - echo Building the Docker image...
      - docker pull 889801477235.dkr.ecr.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/node-15-slim
      - docker tag 889801477235.dkr.ecr.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/node-15-slim node:15-slim
      - docker build -t $IMAGE_REPO_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG .
      - docker tag $IMAGE_REPO_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG $AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION.amazonaws.com/$IMAGE_REPO_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG
      - echo $IMAGE_REPO_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG $AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION.amazonaws.com/$IMAGE_REPO_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Build completed on `date`
      - echo Pushing the Docker image...
      - docker push $AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION.amazonaws.com/$IMAGE_REPO_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG
      - echo $AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION.amazonaws.com/$IMAGE_REPO_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG
```

> buildspec.yml

```
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: /
    destination: /home/ec2-user/First-Alert_Backend
hooks:
  AfterInstall:
    - location: build.sh
      timeout: 400
      runas: root
```

> build.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
docker stop first_alert_backend
docker rm first_alert_backend
docker pull 889801477235.dkr.ecr.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/first_alert_backend
docker tag 889801477235.dkr.ecr.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/first_alert_backend first_alert_backend
docker run -d --network first_alert_network --link first_alert_mariadb:db --name first_alert_backend first_alert_backend 
docker image rm 889801477235.dkr.ecr.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/first_alert_backend
```